# How to setup up .htaccess rewrites for http and https on the same site?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Im having some issues with htaccess rewrites i need to redirect different parts of my site to https rather than http, for example login and news sections. Im not sure how to go about doing this in the correct mannor.

So at the moment I have

```
RewriteRule   ^login/?$  index.php?p=login [R,L]
```

I would like to redirect this to https, I have tried the following but it doesnt seem to work

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/index.php?p=login [R,L]
```

But it doesnt seem to work. am i missing something? I have rewrite on and all other settings as they work. What am I missing?

Also is there anyway to get htaccess to use a different set of rules it https is set to when it is not?

Update:

So what I want to do is rewrite http://www.site.tld/login/ rewrite to https://www.site.tld/login/code and then further rewrite to https://www.site.tld/index.php?p=login. So the user sees: https://www.site.tld/login/ but it is actually doing https://www.site.tld/index.php?p=login

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Specific dir:

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?secure/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/secure/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect all users who are using any part of /secure/ to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/secure/ to https://www.example.com/secure/
# This means if you dont want to force HTTPS for all directories you can force it for a specific sub-section of the site.
```

More here: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Comment: This doesnt solve my problem though, i know how to do the specific http to https trick, but how to i get http ://www.site.tld/login/ rewrite to https ://www.site.tld/login/code and then further rewrite to https ://www.site.tld/index.php?p=login. So the user sees: https ://www.site.tld/login/ but it is actually doing https ://www.site.tld/index.php?p=login